# ListView Item Animation Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation, listviewitem, htcsense

I am currently working on an application in android which involves Listview Animations. I know to animate a listview item. The problem is that I need to animate listview Items like **HTC BlinkFeed**, Which I don't know what kind of technique they are using to achieve that kind of **animation.**

I need a guide or a sample code to achieve that kind of animation. As per my understanding the animation involves Skew Matrix and canvas Draw method override in Listview Class.

Can anyone help me out the logic for the animation or can give me a sample code which mimic the  **HTC BlinkFeed List Item Animation**

Thank you everyone.